# How to define Mock with default Answer in Spring XML

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I'm trying to define mock bean in Spring with deep stubs

```
<bean id="mockLoader" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock" >
     <constructor-arg name="classToMock" value="com.foo.Loader" />
     <constructor-arg name="defaultAnswer" type="org.mockito.Answers" value="RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS" />
</bean>
```

the program is failing with error

> No matching factory method found: factory method 'mock(String,Answers)'. Check that a method with the specified name and arguments exists and that it is static.

but the static method does exist

https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-all/1.9.5/org/mockito/Mockito.html

```
public static <T> T mock(java.lang.Class<T> classToMock,
                     Answer defaultAnswer)
```

What am I missing? is there another approach to create mock with deep stubs?

mockito version is 1.9.5

spring version is 4.0.7

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the static field of `Mockito` could work

```
<bean id="mockLoader" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock" >
     <constructor-arg name="classToMock" value="com.foo.Loader" />
     <constructor-arg name="defaultAnswer">
           <util:constant static-field="org.mockito.Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS"/>
     </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

You might need to add the xml namespace  `xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"`